# Building an Azure Logic App to check new emails received in a shared mailbox and then log an incident into azure sentinel

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm looking at setting up a logic app that will poll a shared mailbox for new messages and then log these as incidents into Azure Sentinel.

So far I have this working

When email arrives into shard mailbox (V2)
+
Create Incident in Sentinel
Description = BodyPreview

is there a way to parse the Email Body to only include the needed information whilst omitting the signatures, any security alerts etc?

The email body includes a snippet at the beginning usually a security context message ie -

"You don't often receive emails from x@domain.com learn why"
"Email has been received from an external sender"

then after the needed content there is the email signature.

If I create the incident with the Bodypreview it includes the header part and only part of the email body I need. and if I use the full email body I get an error adding into sentinel as the description exceeds Sentinels 5000charachter limit.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using split action, you can create incident in sentinel with required content of mail body.
Below are steps I followed,

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- The email received in shared mail box as shown below,
  [image]
- In the compose action taken body of the email as input,
  [image]
- Taken a variable with expression as **split(outputs('Compose'),'Email has been received from an external sender')**, this will remove 'Email has been received from an external sender' from the email body.
  [image]
- Taken another variable to remove unnecessary space from the content **split(variables('removee01'),'
  ')**
  [image]
- Once logic app runs it created incident in sentinel as shown below,
  [image]
- In this way you can create incident with required content.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for this response. How do we handle if the email body as an image embeded within it?